# Adding a framework to existing project

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6, ios-frameworks

I'm adding a 'Cocoa Touch Framework' target to an existing project on XCode 6. Will I be able to use the built framework on older iOS versions? (iOS 6 & 7)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can work around and support iOS7 with dynamic libraries.

> The application must weak link against the framework. To do so, in
>   your application target’s “Link Binary With Libraries” Build Phase,
>   designate the framework as “Optional”. This will weakly link against
>   the framework.

[image]

Then, you need to follow the [guidelines provided by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6).

You can have more information and a sample project in this [blog article](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/103107323582/dynamic-frameworks-on-ios-7).

Comment: Got "ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/MySDK.framework/MySDK) for architecture x86_64"